# Merge Dataframe Columns Containing Lists in Lists Into New Column Combining at Like Indexes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, merge

Given the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

list1 = [['Smith', 'Johnson', 'David'], ['Perry', 'Windler']]
list2 = [['C', 'SF', 'PG'], ['SF', 'SG']]
list3 = [['Injured', 'Injured', 'Not Injured'], ['Not Injured', 'Injured']]

df['list1'] = list1
df['list2'] = list2
df['list3'] = list3
```

I need to combine to create a new column 'list4' with these contents:

```
list4 = list4 = [[['Smith - C - Injured'], ['Johnson - SF - Injured'], ['David - PG - Not Injured']], [['Perry - SF - Not Injured'], ['Windler - SG - Injured']]]

0 [[Smith - C - Injured], [Johnson - SF - Injured], [David - PG - Not Injured]]
1 [[Perry - SF - Not Injured], [Windler - SG - Injured]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a *listcomp* :

```
df["list4"] = [[[f"{l1} - {l2} - {l3}"] for l1, l2, l3 in zip(*lists)]
                for lists in df[["list1", "list2", "list3"]].to_numpy()]
```

Output :

```
print(df["list4"])
                                                                                                                                            
                                                                           list4
0  [[Smith - C - Injured], [Johnson - SF - Injured], [David - PG - Not Injured]]
1                         [[Perry - SF - Not Injured], [Windler - SG - Injured]]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Tested and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['list4'] = \
[['%s - %s - %s'%(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(list1[i], list2[i], list3[i])] \
  for i in range(len(df))]

print(df)
```

```
                     list1  ...                                              list4
0  [Smith, Johnson, David]  ...  [Smith - C - Injured, Johnson - SF - Injured, ...
1         [Perry, Windler]  ...  [Perry - SF - Not Injured, Windler - SG - Inju...

[2 rows x 4 columns]
```